# Check facebook permissions with php

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying to check the permissions that users have allowed for my site and am using the facebook SDK to get the permissions in an array.

```
array(1) { 
["data"]=> array(3) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
["permission"]=> string(9) "installed" 
["status"]=>     string(7) "granted" } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
["permission"]=> string(14) "public_profile" 
["status"]=> string(7) "granted" } 
[2]=> array(2) { 
["permission"]=> string(15) "publish_actions" 
["status"]=> string(7) "granted" } } }
```

i have found some code to search the array to find a specific permission, however I think the SDK has changed since this code was written.

```
if( array_key_exists('publish_actions', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
        // Permission is granted!
        // Do the related task
       $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
} else {
        // We don't have the permission
        // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
        header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" =>    "publish_stream")) );
```

}

i'm looking for a way to search for `publish_actions` and identify whether it is `declined` or `granted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to convert the `permission['data']` array in a more usuable array ...

```
$arr = array();

foreach( $permissions['data'] as $v){

    $arr[$v['permission']] = $v['status'];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Then use your script a bit modified :

```
if( array_key_exists('publish_actions', $arr) && $arr['publish_actions'] == 'granted' ) {
    // Permission is granted!
    // Do the related task
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
    // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
    header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
```

hope this is what you asked ... have fun